# На чем писать бота для масслайкинга?

Tags: javascript, java, python

Появилось желание создать бота, который будет сам лайкать посты пользователей в Инстаграм. Какой язык лучше всего для этого подойдет? В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ботов такого рода можно писать на любом языке. Ведь ни в одном из языков нет встроенной функции "лайкнуть пост" :-). Вам в любом случае придётся использовать внешние библиотеки, котрые позволяют эмулировать работу браузера.

Выбор стоит делать в зависимости от Вашего бэкграунда и опыта на тех или иных языках.

Главная техническая составляющая этой задачи - точная эмуляция действий пользователя при работе в браузере. Это не такая простая работа, как кажется.

Можно копать в следующих направлениях:

1. Полностью программно эмулировать работу браузера. Трудоёмко, но решаемо.
2. "headless" режим браузера и что то вроде selenium: у Вас запущен настоящий браузер "в песочнице", и вы его "дёргаете за ручки"
3. Очень костыльное, но очень наглядное решение: у Вас есть настоящий браузер, запущенный на компьютере или в виртуальной машине. И есть программа, котрая "снаружи" им управляет (фактически - получает изображение экрана, позиционирует мышку и эмулирует мышиный клик)

Только всегда возникает вопрос: а зачем их лайкать?